# Rails javascript partial is not getting updated record

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, partials

I have this view:

```
<!-- Loads custom Stylesheet -->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'simulation' %>

<!-- Loads polling calls to update -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%= render 'show.js.erb' %>
</script>

<!-- Render simulation -->
<%= render 'simulation' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', simulations_path %>
```

It contains these two partials:

_show.js.erb:

```
callUpdate = function(id) {
    if (id) {
        console.log("tic")
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "/simulations/" + id
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Update error, no id passed.")
    }
    $('#sim_div').html("<%= j (render @simulation) %>");
    setTimeout( function() {
        callUpdate(id)
    }, 5000);
};

setTimeout( function() {
    callUpdate("<%= @simulation.id %>")
}, 5000);
```

_simulation.html.erb:

```
<div id="sim_div">
  <h1><%= @simulation.identifier %></h1>
  <h4 class="offset-col-sm-1">Dimensions: <%= @simulation.x_size %>x<%= @simulation.y_size %></h4>
  <h4 class="offset-col-sm-1">Verdict: <%= @simulation.verdict %></h4>
  <!-- REMOVE -->
 <h1> <%= @simulation.dirty? %></h1>

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @simulation.state.each_with_index do |row, y_index| %>
        <tr>
        <% row.each_with_index do |current, x_index| %>        
            <td class="text-center <%= 'dirty' if @simulation.dirty_points.include?([x_index,y_index]) %>"><%= current %></td>        
          <% end%>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
</div>
```

The javascript is calling my controllers update function, which sets dirty records on the update function.

simulation_controller#show:

```
def update
    @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
    @simulation.next # <= THIS SETS DIRTY RECORDS ON THE OBJECT

    @simulation.save

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to simulations_url }
    end
end
```

My javascript code never gets the new updated record from after the update call, and I want it so that when their are no longer update calls to stop calling update and stop the polling. However it only can ever see the initial record which is not dirty. Only the _simulation partial seems to receive the new record (Even though it's getting re rendered by the javascript code so I'm not sure why the javascript can't see the updated record.)

*How can I access properties of the updated record, not just the original in the javascript code?* Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `callUpdate` javascript function likely is in fact being executed every 5 seconds, but it is rendering the same `@simulation` (the initial one) over and over without change.  Your javascript partial is only being rendered once (initial view), and it is making endless ajax requests and endlessly replacing the html of some element with the same contents over and over.

Instead you should be updating the inner html of some element on every **response** of these ajax calls.

Take this line from your initial view:

```
$('#sim_div').html("<%= j (render @simulation) %>");
```

and move it to the response template of your update action (likely to be: `update.js.erb`)